# How to select all things inside brackets in Intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shortcut, keymaps

I'd like to know how to select text between curly brackets, with just two or three shortcut keys.

E.g.: If I have code like this:

```java
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

only the text "*Hello World*" should be selected.

Comment: In your example, "Hello world" is not in curly brackets.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_code_selection), you can use:

#### On Windows/Linux

`Ctrl+W` / `Ctrl+Shift+W`

#### On MacOS

`⌥↑` / `⌥↓`

Each subsequent call to the shortcut selects an increasing range of code (or decreasing, for second shortcut).

Comment: *Option+Arrow Up/Down* on macOS.

Comment: On MacOS I [see](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/30-days-with-intellij-idea-editor-basics/) `Cmd + W`

Comment: It looks like an outdated article. Currently, it's *Option+Arrow Up/Down*, please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_code_selection (switch to macOS shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin out:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11322-bracket-selection

"default mouse shortcut: alt button1 doubleclick or hold alt -> double left click anywhere in between brackets in human terms"